# Enable WebGL in android ionic 2 app

Tags: android, webgl, ionic2

I can see the ol3cesium globe rendered on the web browser, but when i port the .apk to android device, the globe is not getting rendered. It just shows the zoom-in/out buttons and black screen.
This may be because some WebGL settings must be required.

Can anyone please let me know enable webgl settings for android.

Answer (score 0):

What is Android version. Android WebView support WebGL since android 5.0. If you want to use it on lower version you need to use crossWalk

```
compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:10.39.235.15'
```

That lib let you use custom XWalkView that support WebGL.

```
 <org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

But this library is very heavy.